# How could I show the information of each image of the carousel in the modal?

Tags: angular, carousel, ngx-bootstrap

I'm working with Angular and I'm using the Ngx-Bootstrap carousel but I have a small problem. I have a button "See Details" inside each image of the carousel that opens a modal with the information of that image, all that information I have in this.hostlistService.inmuebles that is not more than a simple vector on which I am iterating in the cycle, the problem is that I can not think of how to refer to the modal position of that image when I click on the "View Details" button, what I want is that when I click on the image it shows me the information of that image that is contained in: this.hostlistService.inmuebles. and so for all the images. How could I do it? what I need is like having a reference of each image in the vector to be able to show all the information of that image in that position. What I have in the modal at this moment is just a test I was doing. Here I leave an image of the code and an image of how the carousel is shown.

This is the code where I have the Ngx-Bootstrap carousel:

```html
<app-modal [tipo]="this.hostlistService.inmuebles[c].tipo" [descrip]="this.hostlistService.inmuebles[c].descripcion" [nombre]="this.hostlistService.inmuebles[c].nombre" class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> </app-modal>


<carousel [itemsPerSlide]="itemsPerSlide"
          [singleSlideOffset]="singleSlideOffset"
          [interval]="false"
          [noWrap]="noWrap">
  <slide *ngFor="let imagenPortada of this.hostlistService.inmuebles; let index=index" class="col-md-2 col-12" style="width: 500px;">
    <img src="{{url}}{{imagenPortada.id}}_{{imagenPortada.fotos[0]}}" alt="imagen de slide" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 300px;">
    <!-- <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Slide {{index}}</h4>
    </div> -->
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button type="button" class="mt-2 btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">Ver detalles</button>
      
    </div>
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

This is a picture of the carousel I have so you have an idea:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZsRt.png)

I would be very grateful to the person who can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass the input parameters to your modal component. Instead use `<ng-content></ng-content>`

Now, Have a new component, `<app-image-detail>` which will render the image details inside the modal dialog.

Now the component will become,

```
<app-modal #imageInfoModal>
    <app-image-detail [imageInfo]='selectedImageInfo'></app-image-detail>
</app-modal>
```

On button click of 'See More Details' update the new variable `selectedImageInfo` with the content from `this.hostlistService.inmuebles` and open the dialog.

```
// Intialize modal dialog 
......
@ViewChild("imageInfoMofal") modalDialog = new ModalComponent(); // your <app-modal>
..... 
onButtonClick(imageInfo) {
  this.selectedImageInfo = imageInfo; // from this.hostlistService.inmuebles
  this.modalDialog.show(); 
}
```

`onButtonClick` method will be called in this way,

```
<button type="button" class="mt-2 btn btn-secondary" (click)="onButtonClick(imagenPortada)">Ver detalles</button>
```

Comment: hi @schoolcoder , thank you very much for taking the time to answer. I'm starting with angular and I have not yet come to use what you're telling me. But in the same way I ask you: implementing this method that you mention would show the information referring to each image? In the carousel I am iterating over an array and that array in each position has (apart from the images) other fields such as: name, etc. so if I click on the third image in the modal I have to show the information of the array this.hostlistService.inmuebles [3], and so on. with the method you mention this would work?

Comment: Hi JulianProg, I have updated the code for onButtonClick method to make it clear. Yes, this method will open dialog relevant to the selected image.